# How to delete from a multidimensional array in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I am adding to an array using:

```
server.bans << { :mask => "#{user}", :who => "#{server}", :when => Time.now.to_i }
```

What is the simplest method to reverse this command?

Should I be using `.remove`? If so what should I pass to it, the same as what I used in the `<<`?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Array#pop](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Array.html#method-i-pop) to remove the last element of the array:

```
server.bans.pop
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use [Array#delete_if](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-delete_if), if you want to remove elements which meet certain criteria:

```
server.bans.delete_if{ |u| u[:mask] == "#{user}" }
```

Comment: I think `reject!` is the more commonly used one, but both work the same way.

Comment: Hmm, this doesn't work for me and I'm wondering why. The ban still exists in `server.bans` :-/

Answer (score 1):

You could get the object_id of each element in the Array to use as a future reference. While using pop will work, it is not available once another element of the Array is added.

To view object_id of elements. Possibly store these in it's own Array.

```
server.bans do |ban|
  puts ban.object_id
end
```

Answer (score -1):

Ruby array provide delete_if method to delete items from array conditions. You can use this method as

```
server.bans.delete_if{ |u| u[:mask] == user.to_s }
```

To get more details of delete_if http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Array.html#method-i-delete_if

Further you can also user remove! method

Comment: Is this not the same as @Karsten's earlier answer (except for `to_s`, which is incorrect)?